# How does kubectl detect configuration in GCE?

Tags: kubernetes

I created a Kube cluster using the kube-up script. If I ssh into the intances, kubectl is configured for the local cluster. My question, how is kubectl detecting the kubeconfig when a cluster is created using kube-up script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do this using a cluster built from HEAD on GCE and didn't have the same experience. On the *master* instance, kubectl works. But on the *nodes*, it isn't configured to communicate with the master:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2+", GitVersion:"v1.2.0-alpha.8.82+c9d33ec1b4044e", GitCommit:"c9d33
ec1b4044e2a330a9b8b7a9204a99b6c6eec", GitTreeState:"clean"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

The reason that it works out of the box on the master is that by default kubectl tries to connect to port 8080 on localhost, which is also the insecure port used on the master (until [kubernetes#13598](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13598) is resolved).